# Is there a way to use gmail call phone functionality with empathy/pidgin

Tags: empathy, gmail, phone

Is there a way that I can use this functionality with any desktop client especially something like empathy ? http://www.google.com/chat/voice/

I am referring the phone call function not just video chat which I know how to enable and use both in pidgin and empathy.

Answer (score 1):

There was once an Adobe AIR-based [desktop client](http://rstoeber.com/apps/Google_Voice_Utility.html) for Google Voice available, but it is discontinued. There are [instructions here](http://openjunk.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/add-google-voice-to-empathy/) for how to add it to Empathy, but it requires a gizmo5 account, which has since been [acquired and discontinued by Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_voice#Gizmo5_acquisition). In short, I don't think it is currently possible, with Empathy or any other client.